# pdflatex not working with files which having space in its name

Tags: pdf, pdflatex, clickable, pax

I am using PdfLaTeX and using pax package. I need to combine the uploaded pdf files and generate a composite pdf with links clickable.

It is working when I upload pdf files with no spaces in its name (eg., test1.pdf, test2.pdf). But links are not working when I upload files with space in its name (eg., test 1.pdf, test 2.pdf).

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue.

If you are using pax package and uploading files with space in its name (ie test 1.pdf , test 2.jpg etc).

Before you use the file in includepdf function, you need to add double quotes before and after the filename (ie "test 1".pdf , "test 2".jpg etc) Thus you can create test 1.pax successfully.